# Django user Follow Unfollow Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I am creating a Blog post application and one of my requirements is that users can follow and unfollow one another.
I have created a `profile model class` for each user and in that I have added the `following` column to the `user model` using a many to many field.

People Profile Model ->

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='following', blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True,null=True)
    Phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    Birth_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I am listing all the posts on a webpage and for each post the author is also mentioned on the template. The requirement is that I need to give a button to follow or unfollow the post author.
Now for the first time if the user comes on the page on if the author of the post is already followed that I need to show an unfollow button and for this I need to check every post author followings and make changes to my template as per the response from the DB.

This is the Query that I have written ->

```
posts =  Post.objects.exclude(users=request.user)\
    .select_related('user__people','ProductAvailability').prefetch_related('images_set','Likes')\
    .annotate(comments_Count = Count('comments_post',distinct=True)).annotate(
        Count('Likes',distinct=True),is_liked=Exists(
        Post.Likes.through.objects.filter(
            post_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=user_id
        )
    ),isSaved=Exists(
        Post.favourites.through.objects.filter(
            post_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=user_id
        )),
        isFollowed=Exists(
            People.following.through.objects.filter(
                people_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=user_id
            )
        )
    ).all().order_by('-id')
```

Now the DB shows the record of `user_id = 1` with `people_id = 3` i.e user 1 follows people with id 3.
but the above query returns 0 as output in isFollowed.

Can someone point out the mistake I am making.

Comment: Here the problem that I identified is that in  `isFollowed=Exists(         People.following.through.objects.filter(people_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=user_id) `
Here the `people_id = OuterRef('pk')` should be replaced with `people_id = OuterRef(post.user.people.id)`

But I dont know how I can make that happen as django does not allow this notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a `People` object with as `user_id` the `user_id` and where we are `following` a `User` that has written that post:

```
posts = Post.objects.exclude(users=request.user).select_related(
    'user__people','ProductAvailability'
).prefetch_related('images_set','Likes').annotate(
    isFollowed=Exists(
        People.objects.filter(
            following__post__id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=user_id
        )
    )
).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: Here the following query is not returning the correct result.
The SQL Query generated for this is -> 
`EXISTS(
        SELECT (1) AS 'a'
          FROM 'Backend1_people' U0
         INNER JOIN 'Backend1_people_following' U1
            ON (U0.'id' = U1.'people_id')
         INNER JOIN 'auth_user' U2
            ON (U1.'user_id' = U2.'id')
         INNER JOIN 'Backend1_post' U3
            ON (U2.'id' = U3.'user_id')
         WHERE (U3.'id' = ('Backend1_post'.'id') AND U0.'user_id' = 69)
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS 'isFollowed1' `.

In where clause the correct syntax isn't going

Comment: @TusharSethi: exactly what is wrong?

Comment: In where clause I think It should be 

    `U1.'people_id' = ('backend1_post'.'user_id') and U0.'user_id' = 69`

i.e the author of the post  == people_id from the people_following table

Comment: @TusharSethi: but I assume `user_id` is the primary key of a `User`, not of the `People` model? The two are not equivalent: a user with id = 42, is not (per se) linked to a `People` with id 42.

Comment: no no In the where clause I want to check if people_following table's people_id == post.user.id

Comment: But `people_id` refers to the `People` table, whereas `user_id` refers to the user that person is following. You thus check if the `user_id` refers to a `User` that is related to a `People` where the author (`user`) of the `Post` is in the `people_following` table.

Comment: This thus means that the `Post` has a `user_id` that is referred to in the `people_following` table for the `people_id` that is a `people` record with `user_id` as `user_id`.

Comment: here in the people_following table, there are 3 columns


`1. ID -> unique identifier of the table (Primary key)

2. People_id -> the post author (user) whom we want to follow.

3. user_id -> the currently logged in user.`

So here the currently logged in user will follow the author of the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243299/discussion-between-tushar-sethi-and-willem-van-onsem).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the DB That I have currently. here I have a people table, people_following table, post table and a user table.

and this is the schema for the poeple_following table.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).