# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `people` on serializer `commentsSerializer`

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a blog website and I am using Django rest framework
I want to fetch top 2 comments for a particular post along with their related data such as user details.

Now I have user details in two models

1. User
2. People

and the comments model is related to the user model using foreign key relationship

Models ->

1. Comments

   ```
    class Comment(models.Model):
        comment = models.TextField(null=True)
        Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            related_name='comments_post')
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
            related_name='comments_user')
   ```

The People model is also connected to the user model with a foreign key relationship

People Model ->

```
class People(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='people')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, related_name='following', blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True,null=True)
    Phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    Birth_Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

for fetching the comments I am using rest-framework and the serializers look like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

class peopleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    Name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

class commentsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    comment = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    Created_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    user = UserSerializer()
    people = peopleSerializer()
```

The query to fetch the comments look like this ->

```
post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=post_id).select_related('user').prefetch_related('user__people').order_by('-Created_date')[:2]
        serializer = commentsSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am getting this error ->

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `people` on serializer `commentsSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Comment` instance. Original exception text was: 'Comment' object has no attribute 'people'.
```

Unable to find a way out.

Answer (score 1):

The source is `user.people`, not `people`, so:

```
class commentsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # …
    people = peopleSerializer(source='user.people')
```

In the [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to can specify `user__people`: this will imply selecting `user` and will fetch the data in the same query, not in an extra query as is the case for [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
post_id = request.GET.get('post_id')
comments = Comment.objects.filter(
    post_id=post_id
).select_related('user__people').order_by('-Created_date')[:2]
serializer = commentsSerializer(comments, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Person` instead of <s>`People`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `created_date` instead of <s>`Created_date`</s>.

Comment: wow man that was quick and correct. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: and I had posted another question a few days back and havn't been able to overcome the problem so would you please look at that too. It would be very grateful of you

Comment: Here is the link for that question ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508712/django-user-follow-unfollow-query